# How to avoid CTE or subquery in SQL?

Tags: django, postgresql

### Question

Say we have 1 as foo, and we want foo+1 as bar in SQL.

With CTE or subquery, like:-

```
select foo+1 as bar from (select 1 as foo) as abc;
```

We would get (in postgre which is what I am using):-

```
 bar 
-----
  2
```

However, when I tried the following:-

```
select 1 as foo, foo+1 as bar;
```

The following error occurs:-

```
ERROR:  column "foo" does not exist
LINE 1: select 1 as foo, foo+1 as bar;
                         ^
```

Is there any way around this without the use of CTE or subquery?

### Why do I ask?

I am using Django for a web service, to order and paginate objects in the database, I have to grab the count of the upvotes and downvotes and do some extra mathematical manipulation on those two values (ie. calculating the wilson score interval), where those two values are used multiple times.

All I can work with that I know of right now is the `extra()` function without breaking the ORM(?) [for example lazy queryset and `prefetch_related()` function].

Therefore I need a way to call those two values from somewhere instead of doing a SELECT multiple times when I calculate the score. (Or that's not the case in reality anyway?)

PS. Currently I am storing the vote count as database field and update them, but I already have a model of a vote, so it seems redundant and slow to update vote count and insert vote to database

Comment: In a Django-style ORM-based approach, you would `annotate(foo=...)` these values and then use them like model attributes in later steps of preparing the resulting `QuerySet`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need the sub-query or CTE to do that. There is one alternative though: create a stored procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION wilson(upvote integer, downvote integer) RETURNS float8 AS $$
DECLARE
  score float8;
BEGIN
  -- Calculate the score
  RETURN score;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

In your ORM you now call the function as part of your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT id, upvotes, downvotes, wilson(upvotes, downvotes) FROM mytable;
```

Also makes for cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is by far the best approach in my opinion. Right now, I have managed to get it down to 


`select count(upvotes.profile_id),count(downvote.profile_id), wilson(count(upvotes.profile_id),count(downvote.profile_id)) from ... left join ...`. 
There shouldn't be any ways to further reduce the count query without cte or subquery(?)


For the django users out there trying to do the same thing, you need to subclass RawSQL expression override get_group_by_cols function to prevent django adding count to group by, since the Func expression will not work with a nested Count